# Listing all values in an array

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to populate an array variable using a do loop as follows

```
Do[rayseg[1, i] = i, {i, 1, 5, 1}]
```

This does what I want it to do, however I want to be able to print the whole array. But when I call the variable `rayseg` I get nothing.I need to address specific entries to get usable outputs, `rayseg[1,1]` for example.

I am aware of `Table` and substituting it for the `Do` does the job, however I still want to know how to print off an array created like before because there are some situations where I want to have a variable with depth and I am not filling it sequentially or in any ordered way so table wont do. I then want to be able to list all values within the variable.

Comment: If you want to address specific entries you should look up `Part` in the documentation.

Comment: Os this what you mean? Type `?rayseg` and you get a list of all the defined values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am aware of Part and it is of no use, even when made into a 1 dimensional array the variable rayseg cannot be addressed properly using Part, certainly not to print the whole list ie Part[rayseg,1;;5]. 

And rayseg[[1]]
Gives the following
Part::partd: Part specification rayseg[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: lol "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Comment: What you are building here is *not* an array though.  Are you sure you don't want a proper array instead and do you understand the limitations this brings?  If you are a beginner and do not know the difference between `x[1]` and `x[[1]]`, then I recommend you use the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function that converts to a matrix, assuming that the definitions were made for a symbol with arguments that are positive integers:

```
Do[rayseg[1, i] = i, {i, 1, 5, 1}]

functionToMatrix[functionName_Symbol] := 
 Normal[SparseArray[ReleaseHold[DownValues[#] /. # -> List]]] &[
  functionName]

functionToMatrix[rayseg]

(* ==> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}} *)
```

The take-home message from this question is that `f[i,j]` is different from `f[[i,j]`. The double brackets mean that `f` has a `Head` of type `List` and is therefore what you call a matrix. But with single brackets, the `Head` of `f` is not changed to anything else when assigning something to it. So the "storage method" is very different in the two cases. With `f[1,1] = 3` you create a rule that the evaluator treats the way we expect a *function* to work. So it is not the same as looking up a value in a `List`. Really, functions are implemented in *Mathematica* as rules, and here in particular as rules stored in the `DownValues` of the symbol `f`. That's where I go to construct a matrix out of a function in the above definition.

Comment: ?rayseg was what I was looking for Thank you Jens

Comment: I see - but I also just posted another method.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. This works also. Can you please explain to me what assigning variables in the way I am is (ie rayseg[i]=...) if it is not creating an array. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: yes, it is also good, a much more versatile solution but I cant vote it up sorry :(
This actually suits my needs better because I just need to quickly view the contents of a variable sometimes

Comment: I tried to add a quick explanation to my answer.